# Browser keep loading and never stop

Tags: javascript

From the Chrome developer tool, I can find any error in console, but how can I debug using Chrome to check which script causes the browser keep loading? The problem website is at http://www.852ebiz.com/vote/ph/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I debug using Chrome to check which script causes the browser keep loading?

1. Open Chrome
2. Press Ctrl+Shift+I (Cmd+Shift+I on a Mac) to open the Chrome Dev Tools (F12 also works)
3. Click the Network tab
4. Paste the URL in the address bar and press enter
5. Watch the various HTTP requests, and look for the ones that continue to show "(pending)" for a long period of time

The Timeline column can also be very helpful identifying what's taking time to load.

[image]

Comment: I follow your step but can't see any pending, just only see the loading icon on tab of browser.

Comment: @Kelvin: That's odd, if the loading icon is showing, there should be a "pending" network request. Be sure you have the tools open when you start, and scroll up to see if it's an earlier request (the pending ones aren't necessarily at the bottom).

Comment: Chrowder, I finally find the problem which only occur in Google Chrome Canary